# How to add label with version info from TFS script

Tags: tfs

I have a MSBuild script that I use to change the version of my assembly during build. I want to be able to add custom label as well.

I've tried adding the following:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">    
<Label
      TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
           BuildUri="$(BuildURI)"
           Name="Bss_Release_$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(ChangesetNumber)"
           Recursive="true"
      /> 
</Target>
```

But it seems I'm missing something as I don't see a new label once the build has finished running.

Can anyone help me - all I want is to set the label of the current build

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to indicate *something* to be labelled. Usually, these are source code files. Now what you seem to be missing is a list of items to apply your label on. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa721747(v=vs.90).aspx for the attributes you can use to select the items with that you want to apply your label on. For example, use the **files** attribute to select the source code files to apply your label on.